# Unicode in SQL Server 2012 Express 

Tags: sql-server, database

I am inserting some unicode characters such as Chinese characters using a c# program into a SQL Server 2012 database.

The column I am trying to insert is `nvarchar`, but am still getting ??????? instead of the correct characters. I am getting tweets from twitter and inserting it into a database.

I am using SQL Server 2012 Express. Must I install any language packages or change the settings? I am not really familiar with SQL Server.

This is how i use c# to insert the codes into database:

```
String command4 = "INSERT INTO  tweets ([username], [createdDate], [tweet]) Values ('" + item.user.screen_name + "' , '" + item.created_at + "' ,N'" + escapedString + "')";

SqlCommand insertTweet = new SqlCommand(command4, connectionstring);

insertTweet.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Thank you!

Comment: You don't need anything more - SQL Server is perfectly capable of handling Unicode. Please **show us HOW** you insert your data from C#

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143726

Comment: @marc_s sorry, this is how i insert the data from c# :                                                                   String command4 = "INSERT INTO  tweets ([username], [createdDate], [tweet]) Values ('" + item.user.screen_name + "' , '" + item.created_at + "' , '" + escapedString + "')";
                                                                    SqlCommand insertTweet = new SqlCommand(command4, connectionstring);

insertTweet.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: Also show how you're retrieving it that displays ???????

Comment: @CodeByMoonlight I execute the statement Select * from tweets to execute in the sql express and then am able to see the table

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Comment: Whoops..sorry not really familiar :( I will update now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When passing the characters as SQL strings, always precede with an "N":

```
N'Unicode'
```

instead of just

```
'Unicode'
```

Or in your case:

```
@"INSERT INTO tweets ([username], [createdDate], [tweet]) 
Values (N'" + item.user.screen_name + "' , '" + item.created_at + "' , N'" + escapedString + "')"
```

By the way, **you should [use parameters](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter)**. It would solve many problems at once (like the one you have, date and number formats, security...)

Comment: Parameters Like : String username = item.user.screen_name ?

Comment: No, parameters like SqlParameter (documentation helps). You then put the value into the SqlParameter instance and reference it in your code by name.

Comment: Or even better: **use parameters** instead of concatenating together your SQL statement!

Comment: @mar_s Can u give me an short example on the parameters part? Thank you!

Comment: I had the same problem with Persian (Farsi) words. Preceding them with N solved the issue.